# PostgeSQL Schedule Jobs

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jobs, cron

I am looking a way that can give the ability to schedule jobs on PostgreSQL, for example to schedule execution of some procedures or statements based on interval or on specific schedule.

I tried already the pg_agent but this is a service running in local pc and which enables a schema in PostgreSQL. As a result this cannot be used for remote instances or managed instances.

I am looking a way that they can be triggered from the database context and not from another runtime.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend [pg_timetable](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_timetable).

Comment: Thanks, Is there any native extension coming with the installation of the Postgres?

Comment: No, there isn't, otherwise we would have told you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking where I could find a PostgreSQL coming with these extensions out-of-the box.
Found that:

1. Azure for Postgres Single server has limited extension lists and does not contain something which can act as a scheduler.
2. Azure for Postgres Flexible server has more available extensions and does contain something which can act as a scheduler the pg_cron mentioned in previous answers.
3. Local installation of Postgres can be installed using the StackBuilder Application from EDB where can install also the pgAgent, but this is a service which is going to run on the host machine.

Answer (score 3):

Any job scheduler can satisfy your needs. Either way a client will trigger an SQL statement. If you insist that PostgreSQL should be the service that triggers the statement then you can use [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any native extension coming with the installation of the Postgres?